# Installed git 1.8.4.2 on Mac, but git --version reports 1.8.3.4

Tags: macos, git

I downloaded the latest version of git - 1.8.4.2 - from git-scm.com/download/mac

After I installed it, if I enter git --version in a terminal window, the version is reported as 1.8.3.4.

I ran the uninstall script for both version, but git continues to report 1.8.3.4 on my system.

I'd like to:

- Delete git entirely from my system and
- install the latest version from the URL above.

Can someone let me know the best way to do this?

Comment: do `which git` and make sure it is the one you installed

Comment: @BryanChen - When I run `which git` I get `/usr/bin/git` I'm not sure what to do with that information.

Comment: you need to find out where is the newly installed git

Comment: @BryanChen it looks like the new ver is in /usr/local/git

Answer (score 1):

Rather than removing system binaries (why would you want to do that?) you should do one of two things:

1. Check your `$PATH` and ensure that things *you* install have a higher position in the `$PATH` than the system defaults,
2. Move `/usr/bin/git` to `/usr/bin/git-1.8.3.4`, then symlink the one from `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/bin/git`.

Both of these will allow you to keep both versions in such a way you can choose which to run (providing full path, for example), while also making the most recent install the default.

As an aside, if you've installed from source yourself, I'd recommend building the binary with the version number either in the path or in the binary name (`/usr/local/git/1.8.4.2/bin`). If you're aiming to keep git up-to-date, this will probably save you some hassle down the track when you're installing for the nth time.

If you're on a mac, check out [`homebrew`](http://brew.sh/), too - the [latest `git`](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/git.rb) is `1.8.4.3`, so it appears up-to-date.